# How does Jetpack Compose detect change in variable for recomposition

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose, compose-recomposition

I am doing a Google Codelab and have the following code (drawable changes when button is pressed):

```
@Composable
fun DiceWithButtonAndImage(modifier: Modifier = Modifier) {
    var result by remember { mutableStateOf(1) }
    val imageResource = when (result) {
        1 -> R.drawable.dice_1
        2 -> R.drawable.dice_2
        3 -> R.drawable.dice_3
        4 -> R.drawable.dice_4
        5 -> R.drawable.dice_5
        else -> R.drawable.dice_6
    }

    Column(
        modifier = modifier,
        horizontalAlignment = Alignment.CenterHorizontally
    ) {
        Image(painter = painterResource(imageResource), contentDescription = result.toString())

        Button(onClick = { result = (1..6).random() }) {
            Text(text = stringResource(R.string.roll_text))
        }
    }
}
```

How does Compose know that `result` has changed when it triggers recomposition? Does it detect that through `Image`'s `painter` parameter? Or maybe through `remember` or `mutableStateOf()`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer is in the [documentation](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/state#state-in-composables):

> `mutableStateOf` creates an **observable** `MutableState<T>`, which is an observable type integrated with the compose runtime.
> **Any changes** to this value schedules recomposition of any composable functions that read the value.

In your example when you click the button the `result` changes.  `imageResource` reads this value and it triggers recomposition in nearest scope.
Since the `Column` is an inline function (it means that `Column` doesn't have an own recompose scopes) the content of the `Column` is recomposed.

You can check it visually using this function:

```
fun randomColor() = Color(
    Random.nextInt(256),
    Random.nextInt(256),
    Random.nextInt(256),
    alpha = 255
)
```

Apply the same function to the background color of the `Button` and the `Column`:

```
    Column(
        modifier = Modifier.background(getRandomColor()),
        horizontalAlignment = Alignment.CenterHorizontally
    ) {
        Image(
            modifier = Modifier.background(getRandomColor()),
            painter = painterResource(R.drawable.ic_xxx), contentDescription = result.toString())

        Button(onClick = { result = (1..6).random() },
                colors= ButtonDefaults.buttonColors(containerColor = getRandomColor()),) {
            Text(text = "Button")
        }
    }
```

[image]

Note that in this example the `Image` uses a static resource and not the `imageResource`.

Answer (score 1):

It is quite difficult to answer this question briefly, in a simplified form - Compose uses the Snapshot System to detect changes. It uses an observer pattern to observe changes to state. The parts of the code that depend on the state register change listeners, when the value changes, all registered listeners are notified.

So in your example `mutableStateOf(1)` automatically creates listener in Composer, and `DiceWithButtonAndImage` function gets notified on every sate change.